# Granularity Change from Fiscal Year to Months

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to disaggregate fiscal year (Jul to Jun) amounts into months.

I have a table (t1) of seasonal factors that sum to unity (note: factors are arbitraily set at 1/12 but are different):

| Month | Factor |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | .083 |
| 2 | .083 |
| 3 | .083 |
| 4 | .083 |
| 5 | .083 |
| 6 | .083 |
| 7 | .083 |
| 8 | .083 |
| 9 | .083 |
| 10 | .083 |
| 11 | .083 |
| 12 | .083 |

And another table (t2) of fiscal year amounts, by fiscal year-ending (so, '2019' = Jul 2018 through Jun 2019):

| FY | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2019 | 25000 |
| 2020 | 28000 |

I tried a simple cross-join like this:

```
select datefromparts(t2.FY, t1.Month, 1) a s Date,
       t1.Factor * t2.Amount as MonthlyAmount
from t1 cross join
     t2
order by Date;
```

But the resulting recordset treats t2.FY as if it were calendar year, so that when I SUM MonthlyAmount over 2019-07-01 to 2020-06-01, for eample, I don't get 28000 (which is what I want), but 26500.

I feel like I need some CASE logic within the datefromparts function, but I can't seem to figure this out.  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. A `case` solution to tweak the year is possible. Another possiblity is to use an integer division.

**Sample data**

```
create table factors
(
  month int,
  factor decimal(3, 2)
);

insert into factors (month, factor) values
( 1, 0.10),
( 2, 0.10),
( 3, 0.10),
( 4, 0.10),
( 5, 0.10),
( 6, 0.10),
( 7, 0.10),
( 8, 0.10),
( 9, 0.10),
(10, 0.10),
(11, 0.00),
(12, 0.00);
```

**Solution**

```
select fy.year - (f.month / 7) as year_option1,
       case when f.month < 7 then fy.year else fy.year-1 end as year_option2,
       f.month,
       datefromparts(fy.year - (f.month / 7), f.month, 1) as fiscal_month, --using option1
       fy.amount * f.factor as amount_month
from fiscal_years fy
cross join factors f
order by fiscal_month;
```

**Result**

```
year_option1 year_option2 month | fiscal_month amount_month
------------ ------------ ----- | ------------ ------------
2018         2018         7     | 2018-07-01   2500.0000
2018         2018         8     | 2018-08-01   2500.0000
2018         2018         9     | 2018-09-01   2500.0000
2018         2018         10    | 2018-10-01   2500.0000
2018         2018         11    | 2018-11-01   0.0000
2018         2018         12    | 2018-12-01   0.0000
2019         2019         1     | 2019-01-01   2500.0000
2019         2019         2     | 2019-02-01   2500.0000
2019         2019         3     | 2019-03-01   2500.0000
2019         2019         4     | 2019-04-01   2500.0000
2019         2019         5     | 2019-05-01   2500.0000
2019         2019         6     | 2019-06-01   2500.0000
2019         2019         7     | 2019-07-01   2800.0000
2019         2019         8     | 2019-08-01   2800.0000
2019         2019         9     | 2019-09-01   2800.0000
2019         2019         10    | 2019-10-01   2800.0000
2019         2019         11    | 2019-11-01   0.0000
2019         2019         12    | 2019-12-01   0.0000
2020         2020         1     | 2020-01-01   2800.0000
2020         2020         2     | 2020-02-01   2800.0000
2020         2020         3     | 2020-03-01   2800.0000
2020         2020         4     | 2020-04-01   2800.0000
2020         2020         5     | 2020-05-01   2800.0000
2020         2020         6     | 2020-06-01   2800.0000
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6bcbfca303e3e5e3fa348982a830a94f) to see things in action.

Comment: super slick.  Thank you!